# Querying a table from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to sqlalchemy and oracle. I'm trying to perform a query on a pre existing table(schema or whatever they call it) in an oracle database. However, I get the following error:

Couldn't find any column information for table prefix.tablename

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, create_session

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class NcLiVals(object):
  pass


def loadSession():
  """"""

  db = create_engine('oracle://username:password@host:port/SID')
  metadata = MetaData(db)

  netc = Table('prefix.tablename, metadata, autoload=True)

  netc_mapper = mapper(NcLiVals, netc)

  session = create_session()
  vals = session.query(NcLiVals).all()
  return vals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use schema=prefix as an argument to Table

e.g.

> netc = Table(tablename, metadata, autoload=True, schema=prefix)